# How can <stdint.h> types guarantee bit width?

Tags: c, linker, compiler-construction

Since C is a loosely typed language and `stdint.h` defines just `typedefs` (I assume), how can the widths of ints be guaranteed?

What I am asking is about the implementation rather than the library usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdint.h` is part of the C implementation, which defines the `typedef`s using whatever underlying types are appropriate *for that implementation*. It's not a portable file you can carry to any C implementation you like.

Comment: so the compiler is supposed to understand those as native types such as int and to the magic especially for those. is that correct?

Comment: @nikoss, I don't know what you mean by magic. The point being made is that the compiler is the one deciding the actual width of the types such as `int` (within the limits prescribed by the spec), so the compiler is capable of providing a suitable `stdint.h`

Comment: And further, if the types are agreed upon in *an ABI*, then it need not even be provided by the compiler; the library and/or header implementation can be separate and still have the right types since they're set out in the ABI.

Comment: When I said compiler, I really meant the compiler writers. And yes, their decision is probably heavily influenced by other factors such as architecture and/or OS ABIs.

Comment: @ikegami: I don't mean to object to what you said; I just find it a common source of confusion (see a recent "what does 'the implementation' mean?" question) where these boundaries are when common systems have compiler, linker, kernel, std library, etc. from different parties, and the missing ingredient to understand that is that there's some ABI contract all of them agree on.

Comment: The ABI simply states the parameters have to have a certain size. It doesn't matter what they are called, so the ABI doesn't decide this. It just makes it simpler if everything uses the same name of the same sized type. That's most new languages have fixed sized types. Yet they can still link to the same libraries C does.

Comment: @ikegami: As soon as C++ is involved (normally you want your C implementation to be compatible with C++) it does matter what the underlying types are, because they carry over to function overloading (typically implemented via name mangling, but however you implement it the underlying types matter). So even if `long` and `long long` have the same size in a particular ABI, which one gets used as `int64_t` generally **is** considered a matter of ABI, because it defines part of the C++ linkage ABI.

Answer (score 3):

> How can `<stdint.h>` types guarantee bit width?

C can't and C does not require it.

C does require *minimum* widths.

---

The below, individuality,  are required only on systems that support them, without padding and 2's complement for sign types.

```
(u)int8_t, (u)int16_t, (u)int32_t, (u)int64_t
```

An implementation may optionally have other sizes like `uint24_t`

Below are required.

```
(u)int_least8_t, (u)int_least16_t, (u)int_least32_t, (u)int_least64_t
```

Answer (score 1):

A C compiler eventually needs to compile to machine code. Machine code only has hard, fixed-width types like a 32-bit int, 64-bit int etc. (or rather, it has memory blocks of that size + operations that operate on memory of that size and either treat it as signed or unsigned)

So the people who create your compiler are the ones who define what your compiler actually uses under the hood when you ask it for an `int`, and the `stdint.h` header file is a file they write. It is basically documentation of what they did. They know that e.g. their `long` type is 64 bits in size, so add a `typedef long int64_t;` etc.

On a system where `int` is 16 bits and `long` is 32 bits, they could even have their compiler understand a special internal type and e.g. name it `__int64` and then make `stdint.h` contain a `typedef __int64 int64_t;`.

The C standard just defines that there has to be a `stdint.h` header provided with your compiler, and that if you define `int64_t` in there, it has to map to a data type that is the right size.

*Theoretically* one could just build everything in `stdint.h` into the compiler instead (so instead of using an intermediate name like `__int64` and typedefing it to `int64_t`, they could just use `int64_t` directly, but by using this approach, old code that was written before `stdint.h` existed and defined their own type named `int64_t` can just not include stdint and will thus keep compiling. Names starting with two underscores have been historically reserved for the compiler maker, so there is no chance of existing C code using the name `__int64` already.